# When do FileAdded and FileDeleted get triggered when moving files/folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to understand when the FileAdded and when the FileDeleted get triggered when moving file between sites and within the same site, i came out with this confusing 4 outcomes:-

- Move File/Folder from site to another site >> this will trigger deleted workflow on source
- Move File/Folder within the same site >> this will not trigger deleted workflow on source
- Move File/Folder from site to another site>> this will trigger added workflow on destination
- Move File/Folder within the same site >> this will not trigger added workflow on destination

so can anyone advice why this differ based if the file is been moved to another site or within the same site?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, when you move files/folders from one site to another, you aren't truly doing a move. The actual operation is a copy where a new file is created in the destination site and then deleted from the source site.

There may be some technical reason why it's implemented like this, but it's been like that for as long as I've known, and the core server/database apis haven't changed.